# Why does the Tango Point Cloud lose so much accuracy in the Y direction?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I am using the Tango Point Cloud to place 3D objects in the world, however over time the accuracy of the point cloud worsens.

When I start the app the point cloud lines up with everything correctly but after maybe 10 seconds of moving the camera around the point cloud mesh is hovering about 1-2 inches above the real world objects. It gets worse until I restart the app. Otherwise, it seems ok in the X and Z directions but it always slowly increases in the Y direction.

I found a similar question but I'm not sure it's an offset issue because it looks correct in the beginning, it just slowly gets worse over time: [How to I get more reliable Y position tracking for the Google Tango in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116122/how-to-i-get-more-reliable-y-position-tracking-for-the-google-tango-in-unity)

Also, I tried going back to the Point Cloud example from the Tango github and enabling video overlay so I could compare the point cloud mesh with the real world objects, and it happens there too - the mesh slowly begins to hover above the actual objects.  What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found that [this project](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-placing-objects) (another example project from Google) didn't have the problem with the point cloud losing accuracy. After examining for any differences, I noticed that it doesn't have a character controller for the Tango AR camera. So, I removed the character controller from the camera in both my project and the Point Cloud example from the Tango github and this does fix the problem of bad Y accuracy. (You have to completely remove it from the camera, just un-checking it in the Unity editor doesn't fix it.)